# Select column from table with condition in other table

Tags: sql, postgresql

My 1st table `t1` has columns:

```
t_id, c_id, town
```

My 2nd table `t2` has columns:

```
p_id, year_of_birth, t_id  -- < is ref to t_id in 1st table
```

I want something like this (pseudo-code):

```
    SELECT year_of_birth from 2st where
(
(t_id from 2st) = t_id from 1st) AND (c_id from 1st) = 'text value'
)
;
```

How would this work in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Use a plain `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT t2.year_of_birth
FROM   t1
JOIN   t2 USING (t_id)
AND    t1.c_id = 'text value';
```

[Basics in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries.html)